# Wampserver Upgrade: Environment variable Error

Tags: environment-variables, wamp, wampserver

Today I upgrade WampServer 3.1.0 to 3.13 . After upgradation an error is displaying in Wampserver icon. The error is,
[image]

After searching around with Google, I come to know that there is a unwanted environmant path in the environment variable in my windows system.

This is the list of environment variables existing in my system.
[image]

As you can see there is no variable path showing like in the system. So I'm little weak in OS trouble shooting and I do some investigation using CMD. When I tried to dispaly environment variables via CMD with using **echo %path:;=&echo.%** I'm getting the following result and I can see the PHP variable path as mentioned in the wampserver error.
[image]

So, how can I remove it via CMD or anyother way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting will be in the `Path` environment variable.

So first click on the line containing `Path` under `User Variables` then click the `Edit` button.

That should allow you to look at ALL the PATH settings. Remove the reference to `PHP` if it exists in there

Do the same for the `Path` if you see one in the `System Variables` section, and again remove the reference to `php` if it exists in there.

It may also be a good idea to reboot the PC once these have been removed.